# Can't display fetched image in navigation header

Tags: android

```
public class Drawer extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private TextView textView1, textView2;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        //navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);

        textView1 = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView2 = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        imageView = (ImageView)headerView. findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String Name = bundle.getString("name");
        String Email = bundle.getString("email");
        String photo = bundle.getString("photo");
        Log.d("TAG", "name" + Name);
        Log.d("TAG1", "email" + Email);
        Log.d("TAG2", "photo" + photo);

        Glide.with(this).load(photo).into(imageView);

        textView1.setText(Name);
        textView2.setText(Email);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Drawer.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And this is my error - how can I resolve this?

> 08-25 14:13:42.154 31382-31382/com.example.arun.logintest
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.arun.logintest, PID: 31382
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.arun.logintest/com.example.arun.logintest.Drawer}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2560)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non
>   null View
>                                                                                   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:678)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder.into(DrawableRequestBuilder.java:448)
>                                                                                   at com.example.arun.logintest.Drawer.onCreate(Drawer.java:81)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)  08-25
>   14:13:43.809 31382-31382/com.example.arun.logintest I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 31382 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

You can do another by finding the header layout via `inflateHeaderView` method.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationViewId);
View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
textView1 = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView2 = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
imageView = (ImageView)headerView. findViewById(R.id.imageview);
```

You can now remove `app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"` from your layout file.

Comment: if the textview declaration is removed the app works correctly..user name and photo is not displayed but other fucntions works correctly

Comment: are u getting information in logcat? name, email, photo

Comment: yes i got . But i cant able to display them in the navigation header

Comment: Add your header and drawer layout file and gradle file.